# Cordova browser doesn't support embedded youtube to go fullscreen

Tags: cordova, youtube

I'm using Vue, Webpack, and Cordova.

```
<div class="hello">
    <h1>Videos</h1>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I3DEEaV8IsA?" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

If I load my page, without Cordova, and in a Firefox browser the fullscreen icon on the Youtube video is available and works. When I build and run it as an iOS app, with Cordova, the fullscreen icon is grayed out, and it shows a tooltip that says "the browser doesn't support fullscreen".

Any thoughts why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
allowfullscreen="true"
```

On **iframe** tag.

Comment: Hmm. Try "webkitallowfullscreen='true'". In alternative you may try with InappBrowser..

Comment: webkit didn't work. I would try inappbrowser but I'm not sure where to put that in my vue-cli project.